# Can I get exception stacktrace in kotlin-js?

Tags: javascript, exception, stack-trace, kotlin-js

I've been writing simple web-frontend for application with kotlin-js and faced with a problem of exception handling.
As I see, there is no API to get exception stacktrace: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-throwable/index.html
Is it so?
If it is, may be anyone know some library or snippets to get stacktrace out of Throwable object?

Currently, I've got some workaround for this:

```
import kotlin.browser.window

fun main() {
    window.onload = {
        try {
            throw RuntimeException()
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            console.log(e)
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

Console output is:

```
Object { 
"message_8yp7un$_0": null, 
"cause_th0jdv$_0": null, 
"stack": "captureStack@http://localhost:9080/js/kotlin.js:1767:27\nException@http://localhost:9080/js/kotlin.js:3244:14\nRuntimeException@http://localhost:9080/js/kotlin.js:3255:17\nRuntimeException_init@http://localhost:9080/js/kotlin.js:3261:24\nmain$lambda@http://localhost:9080/js/web-client.js:34:13\n",
"name": "RuntimeException"
}
```

Here, `console.log(Throwable)` exposes underlying JavaScript object properties, and there is `stack` one, but it points to JavaScript code, that is hard to use without source mapping back to kotlin.

**UPD**: it seems like `stack` is not standard exception property, but common one for modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `console.log` to `console.error`

```
import kotlin.browser.window

fun main() {
    window.onload = {
        try {
            throw RuntimeException()
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            console.error(e) // change here
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Kotlin 1.4 the stdlib contains two extensions for this exact purpose
`fun Throwable.stackTraceToString()`
`fun Throwable.printStackTrace()`

Using these we can write

```
    window.onload = {
        try {
            throw RuntimeException()
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, not standard, but it works.
It also handles the source map in Firefox, so I get proper file names and line numbers:

```kotlin
try {
    throw IllegalStateException("ops...")
} 
catch (ex : Throwable) {
    val stack = ex.asDynamic().stack
    if (stack is String) {
        val error = js("Error()")
        error.name = ex.toString().substringBefore(':')
        error.message = ex.message?.substringAfter(':')
        error.stack = stack
        console.error(error)
    } else {
        console.log(ex)
    }
}
```